# How to set a “fake” dimension for an object?

Tags: export, dimensions

I have an object with dimensions (3, 1, 2).

This object will be exported as ".OBJ" to be used in a game.

But for collision purposes, I want this object to be inside an “invisible” box with size (3, 3, 3), like this:

[image]

How to preserve the current object appearance and export it as it has a dimension like a cube?

Comment: usually the collisions are created in the game engine

Comment: It is for Roblox, but due to the complexity of my current script, I would have to change a lot internally in this script to achieve this goal.
It would be easier if the original exported object was in these dimensions that I mentioned ...